# Golang unmarshall mysql format time to time.Time

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have a time of the format `2016-06-16 22:21:00` within an XML document.

I wish to parse that time with Golang.

```
type Price struct {
    Instrument string `xml:"Instrument"`
    Bid float32 `xml:"Bid"`
    Ask float32 `xml:"Ask"`
    Updated time.Time  `xml:"Updated"`
}

type Prices []Price

var p Prices
err := xml.Unmarshal(body, &p)
if err != nil {
    log.Panicln(err)
}
```

My output error is as follows:

```
panic: parsing time "2016-06-16 20:59:57" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 20:59:57" as "T"
```

How can I unmarshal a mysql formatted datetime string as a `time.Time`?

I have read that I need to create a new custom time which implements `time.Time`.

```
type customTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (c *customTime) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    const shortForm = "2016-12-10 01:00:00" // yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss date format
    var v string
    d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    parse, err := time.Parse(shortForm, v)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *c = customTime{parse}
    return nil
}
```

But when I do that, I get the following error.

```
panic: parsing time "2016-06-16 20:59:57": month out of range
```

Comment: I believe you want `const shortForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"`.

Comment: @smarx - Perfect Thanks. I don't understand why your `shortForm` works and mine doesn't. If you write answer with some explanation - I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `const shortForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"`. This is a little weird, but the way `time.Parse` understands formats is that you have to give *this specific time* as an example. See the comment at https://golang.org/src/time/format.go:

> ```
> // These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse.
> // The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
> //    Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
> // which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700,
> // the reference time can be thought of as
> //    01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> // To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look
> // like formatted your way; see the values of constants like ANSIC,
> // StampMicro or Kitchen for examples.
> ```

You can probably imagine why it's important to use a predefined date here... e.g. the library needs to know whether you meant 01/02 as in January 2nd or February 1st. Having a predefined date (cleverly constructed to avoid repeated values) disambiguates.